# JavaScript Encapsulation with WebComponents/ShadowDOM

Tags: javascript, encapsulation, polymer, web-component

Probably simple question, that I haven't really found an answer for:

Does ShadowDOM or WebComponents (as the bigger Standard) actually encapsulate JavaScript aswell? Like having seperate namespaces for each component?

From what I encountered with Polymer that wasn't the case yet, which is obvious, given that polymer is doing it's polyfilling through JS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Shadow DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) and [Custom Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-custom-elements-20130514/) specs say nothing about script encapsulation. The only thing that SD gives you is `<style>` encapsulation and event retargeting (events look like they come from the host element and not internal elements. For custom elements, you can do [tricks](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#constructorattr) to namespace your JS (e.g. anonymous self calling functions, wrapping the constructor in a namespace, etc.)

Comment: Hey, the link to *tricks* is outdated :'(   Can you update it please, I'm keen to know workarounds for this and also a route map

Comment: The article is available in the [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219122200/https://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html) (search for "Can I use the constructor attribute without polluting the global namespace?")