# How to encapsulate external scripts used in webcomponent

Tags: javascript

I am creating a `webcomponent` which uses a [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) library scripts to create codemirror instance.

This `webcomponent` works fine, until it is used in another project which is also using `codemirror`. In that case, page keeps on loading forever. I think its might be because of conflicts of global variables because if I comment out `codemirror` code, it loads fine.

My question, irrespective of above situation, is how can I scope/encapsulate external scripts in `webcomponents`.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976643/javascript-encapsulation-with-webcomponents-shadowdom) has been asked but it doesnt say anything about external javascript scoping.

I am aware that `shadow dom` specs only talk about encapsulating css and not external JS but this is the problem that every `webcomponent` will have since they are meant to be used in someone elses project.

Answer (score 0):

And what errors does DevTools "console" show?

Regarding name conflicts. There are several ways.
The easiest way is not to use global variables in the code. For example, the code can be closed in the structure:

```
(function() {
    // your code here
})();
```

and all variables in your code you declare using var, let or const.
Each declaration of a global variable should be treated as a design error.

The attached component can also be saved as a module and import variables to local variables.
If you must use a global variable for some real reason, you can call an exception when a variable with this name is already defined.

EDIT:

```
var editor1 = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea1, {
    lineNumbers: true
});
var editor2 = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea2, {
    lineNumbers: true
});
```

Where do you see the name conflict?

Comment: Hey. Thanks but this is not an answer at all. I clearly have mentioed that the problem is occuring when using external library (which is declaring global variables). Its not that I am creating some globle variable which is causing problem.

Comment: If you do not create a global variable, how can it conflict with another global variable?

Comment: I use a library named CodeMirror within my webcomponent. It declares a global variable named `CodeMirror`. If my webcomponent is used by someone else's project and if they are importing CodeMirror library as well, there will be conflict. Does that makes sense?

Comment: So, you declare a global variable?

Comment: No. Library does, when I import it in my webcomponent code.

Comment: What is the difference if you personally declare a global variable or did you use a library in which someone declared a global variable? Js is not interested in who is responsible for it, he only sees the global variable. Anyway, where is CodeMirror's global variable declaration? Maybe something has changed.

Comment: "where is CodeMirror's global variable declaration" => Inside codemirror library code, as you would expect. And since its inside the library, I can't change or encapsulate that code. Makes sense?

Comment: It's difficult to talk without seeing a specific code. But 1 line of my answer is the answer to 1 part of the question. Where did you get the name conflict request? What's DevTools for?

Modul / library has to export something, because what would you like to do otherwise? I have edited the answer above adding an example.
You can not overwrite anything unless you use the global variable that someone else has used. Unless the library is badly written and internally uses global variables.
Even then, there will be no error if your code is correct and does not use global variables.